# Intercept file opening event in Linux

Tags: android, linux, unix, posix, inotify

Assume we have a process that may `dlopen()` some third-party library. This library may perform `open("write_only_logfile", O_WRONLY)` on some file to which user has only write access. We need to have an ability to be notified if this library attempts to open a file, so later we may `dup()` returned descriptor and redirect output.
There are few restrictions that make interception harder:

- `LD_PRELOAD` is forbidden - no way to hook `open()`
- `inotify(7)` doesn't help because user has no read permissions on `"write_only_logfile"` and it is owned by admin
- we have no access to library sources and therefore cannot modify it
- `"write_only_logfile"` is hardcoded inside the library, so we cannot pass another name to perform redirecting

I'm wondering if Linux has an efficient way to help in such situation.
Especially taking in account the fact that process may `open()` miscellaneous files pretty often.

P.S. To avoid confusion and understand better - it is a regular Android application with loaded JVM. If app hangs (so called ANR) - system sends `SIGQUIT` to it. Signal is received via dedicated thread that `open()`s `/data/anr/traces.txt` and writes JVM state to it. These data extremely useful for debugging. But app cannot read that file directly because of security reasons (All applications write to it, so there may be somewhat sensitive). Anyway I believe that it is absolutely fair to intercept content that my process would write to it.

P.S.S. In the worst case it is possible to find JVM library image (`libart.so`) and manually patch jump slot for `open()`. But it doesn't sound well.

Comment: Linux makes this relatively hard compared to other OSes. Microsoft's layered driver architecture makes it relatively easy. Many Windows driver books contain an example of a driver for the obligatory encrypted filesystem. I've never seen a good example of layering in Linux. It may be impossible under the current design.

Comment: This is probably the duplicate: [Intercepting file operations on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40161522/608639). In the 40161522 question, he cannot use `LD_PRELOAD` because its not reliable for him.

Comment: @jww nice suggestion but `LD_PRELOAD` is crossed out not because it doesn't work well but because my app started as fork of semi-prepared process. And library that I'm interested in is loaded already. Please see edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are in troublesome situation. Most solutions briefly mentioned below are guaranteed to interfere with SELinux, so don't take my word for any of that.

Debugging your own process with `strace` to intercept `open` is one of usual solutions on normal Linux. I am not sure if it would work in Android; it certainly might become off-limit for non-debuggable apps starting in some new versions (if it is has not been banned yet).

seccomp-bpf is another possibility. Might not be available on older Android versions, but since Android O seccomp is going to be a guaranteed part of Android security getup. Intercept `open` in warn-only mode and give control back to yourself when something interesting happen (via debugging or signals).

If `/data/anr/traces.txt` is opened on-demand, you should be able to observe that by watching contents of `/proc/self/fd/` with inotify or via polling. You might be able to reduce impact of races by setting io niceness of the opening thread…

All of above are only partial solutions, you still might need to decode actual `open` syscall that happened (strace source code might be helpful there for strace/seccomp solutions, readlink for `/proc/self/fd/`) and act upon it (dup2, as you already mentioned).

> "write_only_logfile" is hardcoded inside the library

Is it possible to modify the memory of data segment of the library/executable? Afaik `mprotect` and `PROTECT_EXEC` in particular have been heavily restricted, but at least mmap is certainly permitted (to support JIT compilers etc). It might be possible to cook something up to edit the string constant in place (as long as doing so is possible and allowed, I am not sure myself about that).

Answer (score 1):

If this is just about redirecting writes (and reads) to a single file, you could run the application in a mount namespace with a suitable bind mount for that particular file.  Setting things up in this way probably requires a small SUID binary.

A more general solution quickly approaches a union file system, and getting it right is quite hard.  Even the in-kernel union file system, `overlayfs`, does not manage to provide full POSIX semantics.

Comment: This is a solid proposal, but doesn't using mount namespaces require you to be root unless user namespaces are enabled? And since user namespaces are well-known security hazard, I don't thing that Android would provide them to applications any soon…

Answer (score 0):

You need LD_PRELOAD to hook an application. To hook a third-party library, just load your hook normally before the library (or have it in your executable).

Assuming the library calls `open` from libc and not the corresponding syscall directly, and that it is linked in a normal way, you just have a function named `open` somewhere in your code. Make it call `open` from libc (`RTLD_NEXT` or whatever). The third-party library (and all other libraries of course) will resolve its `open` symbol to your function.

Comment: I have a feeling that the objection to `LD_PRELOAD` is non-technical. It may work in principle, but that doesn't matter if site policy does not allow its use.

Comment: Oh, I've described my problem poorly because I missed such scenario. I cannot use `LD_PRELOAD` and any tricks with dynamic linker because there is no chance to load any custom code earlier than library that should be monitored. Please see edited question.

Comment: "no chance to load any custom code earlier than library that should be monitored" It is not quite clear what you mean. "Assume we have a process that may dlopen() some third-party library". If you can control the process, you are set. If not, it's a strange way to describe the situation. The entire program is third-party.